# How to remove white spaces in CGI Script?

Tags: perl, split, cgi

After using the `split` function, I am storing a URL in the `$sysip` variable.

I have a hyperlink like

```
https://$sysip/home.jsp
```

The problem here is that white spaces are being added to the URL when I click on the hyperlink. It is taking me to

```
%09%09%09(Actualip)/home/jsp.
```

And the page is not opening up. This is happening in Safari browser alone.

The `%09` is because of whitespace. How to trim the white spaces present in the URL?
can anyone please help me? I am very new to CGI script.

Comment: You have a bug in your Perl code. The way to fix this is to correct your code, not to add more code to correct the symptoms. Please show your code and the data. `%09` is a tab character. Are you splitting on space characters, like `split / /, $data`? It may help to split on any whitespace, with `split ' ', $data`

Comment: ($sys_ip, $junk)=split(/\//, $ip);
 print ("<a href='https://$sys_ip/jsp' target=_blank><center><i> Click Here To Launch </i></center></a><br>");
Here Am reading $ip from properties file.

The new window contains https://%09%09%09(ip)/jsp  in address bar.

Comment: Use `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper($ip);` to display the contents of `$ip` before you split it.

Comment: Thank you @Borodin.. Actually, I was looking for these statements. What is this Useqq? Why it is used for?

Comment: It makes `Data::Dumper` display strings using double-quotes, with control characters expressed as printable escape sequences. It is much easier to spot data like embedded tabs and newlines that way. The `Data::Dump` module is better still, but it is not a core modules and may need installing.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove any leading whitespace by substituting it with nothing:

```
$sysip =~ s/^\s+//;
```

Or, if you need trailing whitespace removed, too:

```
$sysip =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g;
```

Comment: Thank you @choroba. Let me try.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to modify specific parts of a URL is to use the [`URI`](https://metacpan.org/module/URI) module.

For instance

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use URI;

my $url = 'https://www.example.com/home.jsp';

my $new_url = URI->new($url);
$new_url->scheme('http');
$new_url->path('/home/jsp');

print $new_url;
```

**output**

```
http://www.example.com/home/jsp
```